# Are willset and didset considered closures in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures, strong-references, didset

I understand the purpose of `willset` and `didset` my I am not sure if they are considered closures.

If they were closures,  shouldn't the following code produce a strong reference cycle?

```
var myProperty : Int = 0 {
    didSet { self.callMyMethod() }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not closures. You can think of it like a special type of function which is not directly accessible; it will only be called when the property changes. (The function is named `myapp.MyStruct.myProperty.didset`; you can see this in the debugger.)

Comment: But if functions are special cases of closures, and willSet and didSet are special cases of functions, then surely they are also special cases of closures? From _The Swift Programming Language_: "Global and nested functions, as introduced in Functions, are actually special cases of closures."